# Style for MenuItem - Image

Tags: wpf

In my MainWindow.xaml I have the following:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon_ResetNetwork" UriSource="/Icons/ResetNetwork_icon.png" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Then I have a menu 
In the menu I have a menu item with the following definition:

```
<MenuItem Command="{StaticResource ResetNetwork}" Header="Reset"
          Icon="{StaticResource Icon_ResetNetwork}"/>
```

I tried to create a general style for MenuItem so I defined in my App.xaml the following

```
<!-- Menu Item -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Consolas"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"  Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Icon">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Style="{Binding StaticResource MenueItemImage}" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The problem is that instead of the icon it presents (The correct) Icon's address
When I define the icon within the menu item (in MainWindow.xaml) in the following way:

```
<MenuItem Command="{StaticResource ResetNetwork}" Header="Reset">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource Icon_ResetNetwork}" Style="{StaticResource MenueItemImage}"/>
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

The item is presented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define object of `Image` to your property `Icon`:

```
<Menu>
      <MenuItem>
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image>
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="/your_assembly;component/your_path_here/your_image.png" />
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

Or:

```
 <ImageSource x:Key="ImageSource">/your_assembly;component/your_path_here/your_image.png</ImageSource>

 <Menu>
        <MenuItem  Header="Reset">
            <Image Height="16"
                   Width="16"
                   Source="{StaticResource ImageSource}"></Image>
        </MenuItem>

    </Menu>
```